# mv folder that match pattern

Tags: linux, move, command-line-interface

I have hundreds of folders to organize according to the folder's name, let's say I have few folders that has name BBC and peppapig as the part of the name

e.g. (folders)

```
 doc_BBC_life
 BBC.nature
 peppapigepisode1
 kidspeppapigseries
 animalsBBC-docment
 newfolder1
 newfolder2
```

Now I want to move folders (there are four) that has the name "BBC" into the subfolder called newfolder1 and same goes for the folder that has the name "peppapig" into newfolder2 folder

Note: each folder has several files that also has the name either "BBC" or "peppapig", I want to maintain the contents without scrambling around.

I want to do something like this "mv *BBC* BBC/

Any suggestion using mv? thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use directly `mv` command to move as follows

```
 mv *BBC* newfolder1
```

And

```
 mv *peppapig* newfolder2
```

You can also do something like this using `find`

```
 find . -type d -name '*BBC*' -exec mv "{}" newfolder1 \;
```

And

```
 find . -type d -name '*peppapig*' -exec mv "{}" newfolder2 \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cannot write a comment, So I have to add an answer:

I tried the solution given by arkascha for me it was producing wrong results:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc1
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc2
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 dir_to_mv
myuser@workstation:~/he$ find . -iname "*bbc*" -type d | xargs mv ./dir_to_mv/
myuser@workstation:~/he$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc1
myuser@workstation:~/he$ cd bbc1/
myuser@workstation:~/he/bbc1$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 bbc2
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Apr 19 21:31 dir_to_mv
```

You can see its not moving bbc directories to dir_to_mv as assumed.
Following will work:

```
find . -iname "*bbc*" -type d -exec mv '{}' ../dir_to_mv/ \;
```

Please note that you need to have directory dir_to_mv in some other path and not in dir you are working on. Otherwise find will produce weird recursive result.

One always have to take care of that with find.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `find` utility to create pretty flexible searches and combine it with the `mv` command using the args` utility:

```
find . -iname "*bbc*" -type d | xargs mv ./BBC/
```

This would move all *directories* within the current folder that have a "bbc" in there name (case *insensitive*) into a folder `BBC`. Moving a directory does not alter or "scramble" its content at all.

Comment: No.  This command moves all folders, including `./BBC/` into the last folder found by `find`.